How to Merge and Propagate Parent Component Translations to a Child Component in Next.js Using next-intl
I'm currently developing a Next.js 14 project that employs the app router along with the next-intl library.
My objective is to facilitate translations for the toast, form, and validation namespaces within the registration-form component. Ideally, I aim to retrieve messages passed down from the parent (via NextIntlContext) in page.tsx, merge them with picked messages, and then pass them along to RegistrationForm.

useTranslations cannot be called without an argument
getMessages function returns all available translations, not just those provided by parent
I don't want to provide all translation namespaces to registration-form component, just the ones it needs


My specific use-case is being able to call my custom useToast hook uses useTranslations hook.

src/hooks/useToast.ts
import { toast } from "sonner";

export function useToast() {
  const t = useTranslations();

  const toastError = (message: string) => {
    toast.error(t("toast.error"), { description: message });
  };

  return {
    toastError,
  };
}

src/app/[locale]/layout.tsx
export default function Layout({children}: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const messages = useMessages()
  const toastMessages = {
    toast: messages.toast as AbstractIntlMessages
  }

  return (
    <body>
      <NextIntlClientProvider messages={toastMessages}>
        <MyToaster/>
        {children}
      </NextIntlClientProvider>
    </body>
  );
}

src/app/[locale]/page.tsx
export default function Registration() {
  const messages = useMessages()

  const pickedMessages = {
    form: {
      registration: (messages["form"] as AbstractIntlMessages)["registration"] as AbstractIntlMessages
    },
    validation: messages.validation as AbstractIntlMessages,
    // ...parentMessages
  }

  return (
    <main>
          <NextIntlClientProvider messages={pickedMessages}>
            <RegistrationForm/>
          </NextIntlClientProvider>
    </main>
  );
}

src/components/form/registration-form.tsx
"use client";

const RegistrationForm = () => {
  const t = useTranslations();

  toastError(t("form.error"))

  return (...);
};

export default RegistrationForm;

